# Spark+yarn - scale memory with input size

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I am running a spark on yarn cluster with pyspark. I have a dataset which requires loading several binary files per key, and then running some calculation that is difficult to decompose into parts - so it generally has to operate across all the data for a single key.

Currently, I set spark.executor.memory and spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead to "sane" values that work most of the time, however certain keys end up having a much larger amount of data than the average, and in these cases, the memory is insufficient and the executor ends up getting killed.

I currently do one of the following:
1) Run jobs with the default memory setting and just rerun when certain keys fail with more memory
2) If I know one of my keys has much more data, I can scale up the memory for the job as a whole, however this has the downside of drastically reducing the number of running containers I get / number of jobs running in parallel.

Ideally I would have a system where I could send off a job and have the memory in an executor scale with input size, however I know that's not spark's model.  Are there any extra settings that can help me here or any tricks for dealing with this problem?  Anything obvious I'm missing as a fix?

Answer (score 0):

You can test the following approach: set executor memory and executor yarn overhead to your max values and add `spark.executor.cores` with number greater than 1 (start with 2). Additionally set `spark.task.maxFailures` to some big number (lets say 10).

Then on normal-sized keys spark will probably finish tasks as usual but some partitions with larger keys with fail. They will be added to retry stage and since number of partitions to retry will be much lower than initial partitions, spark will distribute them evenly to executors. If number of partitions will be lower or equal number of executors, every partition will have twice memory compared to initial execution and may succeed.

Let me know if it will work for you.

Comment: This somewhat works, but it's still semi flakey on long running jobs and some portion of the time I end up with full job failure still (even with a very high maxFailures [>30-50]).  But still, much better than it was previously.  Thank you